# Allow anonymous users to see contents of the Users folder in AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have already enabled anonymous access to AD by setting the `dSHeuristics` property to `0000002` for `CN=Directory Service`. While this allows anonymous users to bind to the directory successfully, when I try to list the contents of the directory, I still don't see the Users folder.

How can I allow anonymous users to not only bind to AD anonymously, but also to read contents from some of the folders in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: open ADSI Edit, select the root of your domain > Properties > Security > Advanced > Add user `ANONYMOUS LOGON` > Select all the relevant "list" and "read" permissions.

Comment: While this works, please note that allowing Anonymous LDAP access can open a security hole. It would be better to have dedicated accounts for your applications. If, in the future, you would want to see who deleted "some object" the security log will tell you "Anonymous user did it" :)

Comment: @iPath I agree with that. This is a test environment though ;) Also, if you select only list and read permissions you should be safe right?

Comment: Yeah, it's ok in a lab. But we cannot say if there are more places in AD that allow anonymous read/list, right? So I would not want to allow a hacker to find such a "place" :) Microsoft had a reason for disabling anonymous access.